# How to prove that the Torus and a Ball have the same Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that the Torus and a Ball have the same Cardinality ?
The proof is using the Cantor Berenstein Theorem.
I now that they are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ so I can write $\leq \aleph$ but I do not know how to prove $\geqslant  \aleph$.
Thanks

Comment: @Henry:Both sets can be dissected into circles.This is answer your question?

Comment: Show that each has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

Show that a circle is equipotent with $[0,2\pi)$ by fixing a base point, and sending each point on the circle to its angle, where $0$ is the base point.

Since both the torus and the ball contain a circle, both have at least $\aleph$ many elements.

Comment: In this answer, taking context from the question, $\aleph$ is the cardinal number of the real numbers.

Comment: May I write this following: because $[0,2\pi ]\subseteq S $ and $\left |[0,2\pi ] \right |=\mathbb{R}$ then $\left |S \right | \leqslant \mathbb{R}$. we now that $\left | S \right |\leq \left | \mathbb{R}^{n} \right |$ then $\left | S \right |=\mathbb{R}$ and the same thing for a Torus?

Comment: @Heran: you want the other side, namely $|\mathbb R|\leqslant|S|\leqslant|\mathbb R^n|=|\mathbb R|$.

Comment: :Yes I made a type error |R|$\leqslant $|S|

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're talking about solid balls and tori in $\mathbb R^3$.

To prove that these sets are equipollent using the [Cantor–Bernstein–Schröder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem), all you need to do is to show that:

1. there exists an injection $f$ from the ball $B$ into the torus $T$, and
2. there exists an injection $g$ from the torus $T$ into the ball $B$.

The CBS theorem then says that there exists a bijection between $B$ and $T$.

If you're given explicit geometric definitions of $B$ and $T$, you can use these directly to construct invertible [affine maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) $f$ and $g$ such that $f(B) \subset T$ and $g(T) \subset B$.
Another, more general way to do this is to note that both of these subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ are [bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set) and have non-empty [interior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29).  Thus, for each of them, there exists [open balls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_ball) $I$ and $O$ such that $I_B \subset B \subset O_B$ and $I_T \subset T \subset O_T$.  Then choosing $f$ and $g$ (again as affine maps) such that $f(O_B) = I_T$ and $g(O_T) = I_B$ will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume known the fact that $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$ have the same cardinality for all pairs of positive integers $(m,n)$.

Then the following follows easily: Let $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ such that there exists a subset $A\subset X$ homeomorphic to an open subset of $\Bbb R^m$ for some $m\leq n$. Then $|X|=|\Bbb R^n|$.

Indeed, such an $A$ obviously contains an open segment $I$ (e.g. any radius of any open ball contained in $A$) and the chain of inclusions
$$
I\subset A\subset X\subset\Bbb R^n
$$
together with the fact that $|I|=|\Bbb R|=|\Bbb R^n|$ shows that $|X|=|\Bbb R^n|$.

It is clear that both the ball $B$ and the torus $T$ (no matter whether you take the solid shapes or just their surfaces) satisfy the property required for $X$, thus $|B|=|\Bbb R^3|=|T|$.